# I want to do a sort with the alphabetic order in a table with cypress but this error appears expected [ Array(14) ] to deeply equal [ Array(14) ]

Tags: node.js, sorting, cypress

Check that the list of accounts is ordered according to the rules below :

1- Company (Alphabetic order)

2- currency ( TND is the first currencydisplayed  then Euro then USD  then we apply the alphabetical sort rule)

```
 cy.get('#accounts-list-table tbody tr')
  .find(`td:eq(${companyColumnIndex})`) // Select the td in the found Company column
  .invoke('text')
  .then(companyNames => {
    cy.log('Original Text:', companyNames);

    // Ensure the content is not empty before attempting to split
    if (companyNames.trim().length > 0) {
      const companyNamesArray = companyNames.trim().split(/\s+/);
      const sortedByCompany = [...companyNamesArray].sort();

      // Log the trimmed and sorted arrays for debugging
      cy.log('Trimmed and Sorted Array:', sortedByCompany);

      // Use deep.equal for array comparison
      expect(sortedByCompany).to.deep.equal(companyNamesArray); // Reversed order in comparison
    } else {
      // Handle the case when the content is empty
      cy.log('Warning: Empty content in the Company column');
      expect([]).to.deep.equal([]); // Empty array to ensure the test doesn't fail in this case
    }
  });
});
```

**The error "expected [ Array(14) ] to deeply equal [ Array(14) ]"** after .then(companyNames => {.......
please any solutionls to fix my code

Comment: The issue is you're asserting deep equality of 2 arrays with different sort order, which will not pass.  I'm not overly familiar with Cypress, though, so not sure what to suggest for a fix...

Comment: squillman - That is the point of the test - it should pass if and only if `companyNames` are sorted on the web page already, so it's raison d'être for the test.

Answer (score 0):

The not enough debugging information, but I'll take a guess.

The way you separate the texts with `.split(/\s+/)` will fail if there are spaces in the `companyNames`.

To avoid that issue, extract text from on individual `<td>` not on the list of `<td>`.

- `.find('td:eq(${companyColumnIndex})').invoke('text')` gives you one string with all the names concatenated.
- `.find('td:eq(${companyColumnIndex})').then((cells$) => Cypress._.map(cells$, 'textContent'))` gives you an array of individual company names

Implementing:

```js
 cy.get('#accounts-list-table tbody tr')
  .find(`td:eq(${companyColumnIndex})`) 
  .then((cells$) => Cypress._.map(cells$, 'textContent'))
  .then(companyNamesArray => {
    const sortedByCompany = [...companyNamesArray].sort();
    expect(sortedByCompany).to.deep.equal(companyNamesArray); 
  })
})
```